# Ordering Entity Framework Query by specific Value

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a Backgrounds table in Entity Framework for a MVC C# Webpage.

I want the user to be able to choose from the supplied backgrounds. Each background record has 3 columns:

```
Country | State | City
```

Now I want the backgrounds to first be returned where user.City = Background.City, then by User.State = Background.State, then by User.Country = Background.Country then the rest.

To add a little bit more complexity, I would prefer the order to be randomised to each user - this isnt 100% necessary but would be good to prevent alot of people from the same city choosing the same background (we can use the userId or another way to seed a fake random output that is unique to the user). I also require Paging. (meaning the Order By Function I choose will need to be constant. for that user)

My first attempt, was returning the same image many times and was:

```
        return DbContext.Backgrounds.Where(a => a.Deleted != true)
            .OrderBy(a => a.City.ToLower() == city.ToLower() ? 0 : 1)
            .ThenBy(a => a.State.ToLower() == state.ToLower() ? 0 : 1)
            .ThenBy(a => a.Country.ToLower() == country.ToLower() ? 0 : 1);
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want orderby.. but also want random, then also have server side paging where you get a new random result each time you hit the server for paging while keeping track of the random paging...

Comment: The random order (per section ) more  a wish list. But it would be randomised perr user (based on user id int). Therefor if same user requests more the order woulf be the same. - yes its a tall order

Comment: Reason behind randomised order is if 2 users from new york city register. I dont want them seeing the same first 8 backgrounds (i may have 30 images for nyc) users are more likely to always choose from first 8. If they click more itll show more from nyc until they are exhausted then show more from ny state until echausted then from usa etc

Comment: I see what you mean.  The randomized order is easy, the paging is going to be tough since your getting random, unless you wanted to store what values you have already taken and filter them out in the query .

Answer (score 0):

So you are ok with ordering. The only thing is to randomise the output not violating `(Country|State|City)` ordering. You also want to have this order to be preserved for a particular user when he executes the query once again.

1. Define `BackgroundHash` class:

   ```
   public class BackgroundHash
   {
       public string Hash { get; set; }
       public int Id { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. `userId` should be used as a seed for a `MD5` sql hashing function. The query may be look like this

   ```
   var sql = @"SELECT 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', @userId + cast(Id as nvarchar(20))), 2) as Hash, 
       Id from Backgrounds";
   return DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<BackgroundHash>(sql, new SqlParameter("userId", userId.ToString()))
       .Join(DbContext.Backgrounds.Where(a => a.Deleted != true), ou => ou.Id, i => i.Id, (hs, b) => new { hs, b })
       .OrderBy(p => p.b.City.ToLower() == city.ToLower() ? 0 : 1)
       .ThenBy(p => p.b.State.ToLower() == state.ToLower() ? 0 : 1)
       .ThenBy(p => p.b.Country.ToLower() == country.ToLower() ? 0 : 1)
       .ThenBy(p => p.hs.Hash);
   ```